# ServiceStack not showing up in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, rest, soap, servicestack

According to this documentation:
https://youtu.be/EaUcPXVeLpk?t=20

I should be able to right click and select "Add ServiceStack Reference"

I don't see that option:
[image: Text]

I am using VS2019

Comment: Right click on IDQPOC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [ServiceStackVS VS .NET Extension](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStackVS) feature, did you [install ServiceStack VS](https://docs.servicestack.net/install-servicestackvs)?

Comment: Your post came up in the Low Quality Post queue. Is there any way you can rephrase this to sound less like a question?

Comment: I was missing the extension. Thanks